# Is it possible to load session by SID in php?

Tags: php, api, session

I am working on API, where by default cookies are used, but also should be possile to load session data by sid.

So, scenario looks like the following:

1. Client makes a request with a cookie and/or with SID parameter
2. We check, if SID is defined - we load session data by SID
3. If SID is not defined - we use SID, that is defined in a cookie

My first idea was to use `session_id()` function to load session data for specified SID, but i found that this function does not do this - it just overwrites current session id, but does not load any data for specified SID.

Is it possible to load different session in PHP for different SID?

Comment: `session_id` *should* do it. How are you using it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `session_id` *before* you call `session_start`